# Teamcity - Check if git merge resulted in conflict

Tags: teamcity

In TC, my first build step is to merge in the current branch into the `develop` branch. I'm doing it this way.

```
"%env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH%" branch -D develop
"%env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH%" checkout develop
"%env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH%" pull
"%env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH%" merge %teamcity.build.branch%
```

However, if there is a merge conflict, I want to exit out of the build. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Under the Configuration settings for the project, do the following:

1. On the left side panel go to **Failure Conditions**.
2. Then at the bottom, under **Additional Failure Conditions**, press **Add failure condition**.
3. Select "**Fail build on specific text in build log**".
4. Add in the text which appears in the build log when there are merge conflicts.
5. Tick **Stop build**.
6. Press **Save**.

[image: TeamCity add failure condition]

Now I don't know the exact text to enter but when you try and complete the build step, in the build log (after running the build) when you get a merge conflict, you should see some text indicating there was a merge conflict.

Add that text into the failure condition and that should work!

*Note: Make sure the text you choose from the build log would only appear when there is a merge conflict.*

Comment: After you find out the text to use for the failure condition, please comment it so I can update the answer for future readers :)

Comment: That's a really good idea. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it'll do for now.